# UWP change language without changing the currency

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, multilingual

I need to change the language, but keep the currency and date/time format. How to do this?

I've tried the following (the currency and date/time format must be in en-US):

```
ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "zh";
Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();

var fixedCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = fixedCulture;
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = fixedCulture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = fixedCulture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = fixedCulture;
```

The language does get changed to Chinese (ie. the resource string refers to "zh" folder) as well as the currency symbol and the date/time format.

My question is, how to change the language without changing the currency and date/time format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By default, the currency and date/time are formatted according to the conventions of the current application language. So if you change the **PrimaryLanguageOverride** setting, the format of currency and date/time will also change.

To override the default setting, we can use [DateTimeFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter) and [CurrencyFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Globalization.NumberFormatting.CurrencyFormatter).

For example, for date/time format, we can use the following formatter like:

```
var dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter("shortdate longtime", new[] { "en-US" });
var dateTimeString = dateTimeFormatter.Format(DateTime.Now);
```

And for currency format, we can use a formatter like:

```
var currencyFormatter = new CurrencyFormatter(CurrencyIdentifiers.USD, new[] { "en-US" }, "US");
var currencyString = currencyFormatter.Format(123.456);
```

For more info, please see [Date and time formatting sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DateTimeFormatting) especially Scenario 4 and [Number formatting and parsing sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/NumberFormatting) especially Scenario 3.

> The problem is that I need to obey the actual system language setting.

To retrieve system language setting, we can use we can use [Globalization​Preferences.Languag‌​es](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.userprofile.globalizationpreferences#Windows_System_UserProfile_GlobalizationPreferences_Languages) property. This property gets the set of languages that are preferred by the user, in order of preference. The first language in this list would be the system language.

```
//Obtain the user's system language setting.
var sysLanguage = Windows.System.UserProfile.Globalization​Preferences.Languages[0];
```

[Globalization​Preferences Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.userprofile.globalizationpreferences) also have a [Currencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.userprofile.globalizationpreferences#Windows_System_UserProfile_GlobalizationPreferences_Currencies) property which can be used to [CurrencyFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Globalization.NumberFormatting.CurrencyFormatter) like the following:

```
var currencyFormatter = new CurrencyFormatter(Windows.System.UserProfile.Globalization​Preferences.Currencies[0]);
var currencyString = currencyFormatter.Format(123.456);
```

---

> I put in "Indonesian" (language code: id) and it doesn't work :(

I'm not familiar with Indonesian. I tried adding "Bahasa Indonesian" in **Languages** and set it as default.
[image]
However, this didn't change the **Windows display language**. The system still display in English. And by default, the currency is set according to Windows display language. See  **Settings > Time & language > Region & language > Additional date, time, & regional settings > Region: Change date, time, or number formats**.
[image]

So this might be why my solution didn't work for Indonesian. For some other languages, such as Chinese, Japanese and France, if we set them as default , the Windows display language would also change.Thus they can work.
[image]

Anyway, in my solution, it always obtain the user's system setting. And usually, we should respect user's setting (I'd suppose if the user uses Indonesian language and does not want to use English format, he/she will change to Indonesian format). If you do want to use the currency format according to the default language, you can still take advantage of `CultureInfo` like:

```
12345.6789.ToString("C3", new CultureInfo(Windows.System.UserProfile.Globalization​Preferences.Languages[0]))
```

Comment: Hi Jay, I have considered using this, but I can't. The problem is that I need to obey the actual system language setting. I just need to translate the text. For example, if the system language setting is in en-US, then I need to obey the format (even though the user choose the language in Chinese). If the system language is in en-AU, I need to obey the format (eg. dd/MM/yyyy instead of MM/dd/yyyy).

Comment: @Sam Sorry for the late response. According to your comment, what you need is getting system language. Then you can try with `Windows.System.UserProfile.Globalization​Preferences.Languages`. I've updated my answer, please have a check.

Comment: Hi Jay, I just put your solution in. It worked with the Chinese, but not for all other language? For example, I put in "Indonesian" (language code: id) and it doesn't work :(

Comment: Hi Jay, I revert back to use my current solution (not yours), for some reason, Chinese also worked. But not Indonesian (language code: id). If you tried multiple times, then it will work (switch English -> Indonesian -> English -> Indonesian -> Then it will show $ sign instead of Rp). Any idea?

Comment: @Sam I'd think the problem here is related to Indonesian language. You can check my update. And I think you can still use `CultureInfo` according to your requirement.